# How to select nth child of mth element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've been looking for my problem but I could'nt find the exact solution. I want to select a child element (e.g 2nd child) of an element with a class name (e.g 3rd element of element with "some-class" class name). In a nutshell, second child of the third element of a class.

I've tried combining `:eq(2)` and `:nth-child(2)`, but apparently it's not working.

```js
var result = $(".some-class:eq(2) :nth-child(2)");
```

The result is `undefined`.

**HTML format:**

```
<div class="some-class">Some content</div>
<div class="some-class"><Some content</div>
<div class="some-class">
  <p>Some paragraph</p>
  <p>THE ELEMENT I WANT TO SELECT!<p>
  <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what's your html

Comment: Hi @Motion, shall you html format, we didn't get you

Comment: Unable to replicate: https://jsfiddle.net/avzLg734/